# How to create a list contains alternating interval list of numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 lists of numbers:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

B = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 200]
```

Then I would like to make a combination for each X and Y from each element of A and B with alternating interval as follows. The total elements of X and Y is always odd (3,5,...) until the last odd number before n. In the case of n = 10, then it is up to 9.

```
X = [A_1, B_2, A_3, ...,A_idx_odd], len(X) = odd
Y = [B_1, A_2, B_3, ...,B_idx_odd], len(Y) = odd
```

Then, for each combination of X and Y will be stored in the storage_X and storage_Y.

```
storage_X = [ [len(X) =3], [len(X) = 5], ..., [len(X) = 9]]

storage_Y = [ [len(Y) =3], [len(Y) = 5], ..., [len(Y) = 9]]
```

For example:

```
X = [1, 102, 3]               len(X) = 3
X = [1, 102, 3, 104, 105]     len(X) = 5

storage_X = [[1, 102, 3], [1, 102, 3, 104, 105], ....]   

Y = [101, 2, 103]             len(Y) = 3
Y = [101, 2, 103, 4, 105]     len(Y) = 5

storage_Y = [ [101, 2, 103], [101, 2, 103, 4, 105] , ....]
```

How can I do in python?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't understand what what the output should be from this description, I can't undertand what the underlying rule is, and I certainly can't understand what any of this is supposed to do with Python.

Comment: Do A and B always have the same size?

Comment: Hi @mozway, yes. A and B will be always the same.

Comment: Hmm, so you want a list of list as output?

Comment: Yes, @mozway. So, the output will be from the smallest odd len until the largest possible odd len. For example, the number of each element (list) in storage_X consists of list_X from 3 elements, list_X from 5 elements, list_X from 7 elements, and list_X from 9 elements. (as posted)

Comment: Hi @mozway, do you think is it possible to use the concept of "append" to form each of X and Y? What I mean is X.append(A[0]).append(B[1]).append(A[2]).

Comment: @Nicholas you could maybe but this would probably be quite less efficient. Any reason?

Comment: Yes, @mozway. It is because I use q_i*p_i + (1-q_i)*c_i where q=np.remainder(i,2) or q=i mod(2) to get the element from A and B. Note: i = index of A or B.

Comment: @Nicholas it looks like you could do such a condition, and probably without append, but I'd suggest to open a new question and provide a clear example of what you want to do

Comment: Hi @mozway , I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75399077/17901455 , thank you.

Comment: Hi @mozway, I posted a similar question. Perhaps do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75470040/17901455  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### With pure python:

```
X_storage = [[[A, B][j%2][j] for j in range(i)] for i in range(3, len(A), 3)]
# [[1, 102, 3],
#  [1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106],
#  [1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106, 7, 108, 9]]

Y_storage = [[[B, A][j%2][j] for j in range(i)] for i in range(3, len(A), 3)]
# [[101, 2, 103],
#  [101, 2, 103, 4, 105, 6],
#  [101, 2, 103, 4, 105, 6, 107, 8, 109]]
```

#### Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 200] 

m = np.arange(len(A))%2
X = np.where(m, B, A).tolist()
Y = np.where(m, A, B).tolist()

X_storage = [X[:i] for i in range(3, len(A), 3)]
# [[1, 102, 3], [1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106], [1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106, 7, 108, 9]]

Y_storage = [Y[:i] for i in range(3, len(A), 3)]
# [[101, 2, 103], [101, 2, 103, 4, 105, 6], [101, 2, 103, 4, 105, 6, 107, 8, 109]]
```