# How to append for loop based on given index as parameter and rule?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[image: List equations]
I would like to apply this rule from two set of lists p and c with total n = 6.

Equation 1: a set of integer number with len(p) = 6 and index is in ascending order.

Equation 2: a set of integer number with len(c) = 6 and index is in ascending order.

Equation 3: the remainder of the index i divided by 2.

for example: i = 1 then q = 1 and i = 2 then q = 0. So, the set of q for n=6 is {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}.

Equation 4: the order of the objective list (P) starts from index n, 1, 2,...,(n-1). In the case of n=6, then the index for P is [6,1,2,3,4,5]

Equation 5-8: to match the index of the objective list (P) with the index from p and c. Please note that equation 5 is not applicable in the case of n = 6.

Equation 9: A is a set of possible combination from P with maximal len(A) is odd. In the case of n=6 then the possible combination is len(A) = 3 and len(A) = 5.

Note that the index for equations 6 to 9 have been solved by creating a set of list **storage_i** and its respective equation 3 is **q** in the code.

Next, my challenge is to code the equation 6 to 9 to get the value from the respective p and c and index i in the storage_i.

Expected Output:

```
A = [[c_6, c_1, p_2], [c_6, c_1, p_3], ..., [c_3, p_4, c_5], [c_6, c_1, p_2, c_3, p_4], ...., [c_1, p_2, c_3, p_4, c_5]]

or 

A = [[20,7,120], [20,7,3], ...,[80,50,9], [20,7,120,80,50], ...,[7,120,80,50,9]]
```

This is the parameters as explained:

```
import numpy as np

p = [100,120,3,50,200,90]
c = [7,100,80,220,9,20]

storage_i = [[6, 1, 2],
 [6, 1, 3],
 [6, 1, 4],
 [6, 1, 5],
 [6, 2, 3],
 [6, 2, 4],
 [6, 2, 5],
 [6, 3, 4],
 [6, 3, 5],
 [6, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 [6, 1, 2, 4, 5],
 [6, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

q = [[0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

For example (not python index):

```
storage_i[1] = [6, 1, 2] and q = [0, 1, 0], then:
A_cc = q[6]*p[6] + (1-q[6])*c[6] = 0*90 + (1-0)*20   = 20
A_c  = q[1]*p[1] + (1-q[1])*c[1] = 1*100 + (1-1)*7   = 100
A_cc = q[2]*c[2] + (1-q[2])*p[2] = 0*100 + (1-0)*120 = 120 

A = [A_cc,A_c,A_cc] = [20,100,120] 

Another example:

p = [100,120,3,50,200,90]
c = [7,100,80,220,9,20]

storage_i =  [1, 2, 3], and q = [1, 0, 1], then:
A_cc = q[1]*c[1] + (1-q[1])*p[1] = 1*7 + (1-1)*100   = 7
A_c  = q[2]*p[2] + (1-q[2])*c[2] = 0*120 + (1-0)*100 = 100
A_cc = q[3]*c[3] + (1-q[3])*p[3] = 1*80 + (1-1)*3 = 80 

A = [A_cc,A_c,A_cc] = [70,100,80]
```

Here I am not sure how to append the A_cc and A_c based on equation 6-9.

```
storage_var_R5 = []

for set_i in storage_i:
    temp_var_R5 = []
    for idx_i in set_i:
        if idx_i ==n:
            A_cc = q[idx_i]*p[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*c[idx_i]
        else:
            A_c = q[idx_i]*p[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*c[idx_i]
            A_cc = q[idx_i]*c[idx_i] + (1-q[idx_i])*p[idx_i]
        temp_var_R5.append()
```

Can anyone help me, please?
In case you need further clarification, please feel free to let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @mozway, perhaps do you have any idea on this case ? ^^

Comment: What is your question precisely ? How to append two numpy arrays ?

Comment: Hi @obchardon, I am not sure how to append the result of A_cc and A_c into A = [A_cc, A_c, A_cc,...., A_cc]. Based on the storage_i, if len(A) = 3 then A = [A_cc, A_c, A_cc] and if len(A) = 6 then A = A = [A_cc, A_c, A_cc,  A_c, A_cc]. I also provided more example on the initial post. Let me know if anything needs to be clarified, thank you.

Comment: @NicholasNicholas your equations in the code snippet do not match the mathematical equations enumerated at the top of the question. Equation 5 seems to be completely missing, for example. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hi @v0rtex20k, yes. It is intentionally. The equation 5 is not applicable for this case.

Comment: @NicholasNicholas ah, I see your comment now. The thing that confuses me most is storage_i - why does it jump from lists of length three to lists of length 5?